# error : this appp wont runt without google play service which missing from your phone. get your google play service

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

please help,

where is the wrong please? i have installed google play service from sdk and import it , and then add it from project->property->android->add .

i have the key for google-map android v2 successfully,

i have 2 AVD with different target, 1 with target Android and other with target google api.
and both give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Please install google play services from SDK manager

Answer (score 0):

You can't Test Google Maps in Emulator.
try with device.

there are some ways you can find on google but they are not working as per required.
i prefer you use device for testing Google Map functionality.

Comment: Thanks for respon, 
so is that error message are normal for google maps? 
because i tried in my device and still error.

Comment: @muhibunsyairoji can you post logcat?

Comment: Here is the error message in my logchat :

11-27 00:38:33.456: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1267): Google Play services is missing.
11-27 00:38:33.506: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1267): Google Play services is missing.

11-27 00:38:33.586: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1267): Google Play services is missing.